# addvaluechangedHandler fires twice in gwt..what alternate method shall i use?

Tags: gwt, date

I am using following code.
But `addvaluechangedHandler` fires twice in gwt.
what other method should i use so that it will occur only once?

```
calendar.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {  
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {

        Date newDate = calendar.getValue();
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+1);       
        if ((newDate.before(todaysDate))) {
            Window.alert("You can not choose past dates before " +todaysDate);
            calendar.setValue(null);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4785

The workaround seems to be:

```
public class DateBoxOneEvent extends DateBox {
  @Override
  public void setValue(Date date, boolean fireEvents) {
    if (date != null) {
      date.setHours(0);
      date.setMinutes(0);
      date.setSeconds(0);
    }
    super.setValue(date, fireEvents);
  }
}
```